# Javascript function in a object issue with infinite loop

Tags: javascript, function, compiler-errors

Was trying to declare a function in my object but inside my code it is saying infinite loop within my code. I tried to declare it as a normal function but my IDE only wants it declared like it is below but yet it says infinite loop when I compile it.

```
let movie = {
  title: "Forrest Gump",
  director: "Robert Zemeckis",
  composer: "Alan Silvestri",
  budget: 55000000,
  boxOffice: 677900000,
  awards: [],

  totalRevenue: function () {
    let x = this.movie.boxOffice - this.movie.budget;
    return x;
  },
};
```

Comment: If you're asked to add more details, then add more details, don't work around the rules. "_my IDE_" What is it? JS is not compiled in an IDE, are you working with ex. TypeScript?

Comment: I see precisely no looping in this post. Where is the 'infinite loop' you are speaking of?

Answer (score 1):

Delete `movie` in your function:

```
totalRevenue: function() {
    let x = this.boxOffice - this.budget;
    return x;
},
```

Your code is error because it's trying to find an object called "movie" in `this` object which you don't have. Your function will work if you make your object like this:

```
let movie = {
    title: "Forrest Gump",
    director: "Robert Zemeckis",
    composer: "Alan Silvestri",
    budget: 55000000,
    boxOffice: 677900000,
    awards: [],
    movie: {
        boxOffice: 677900000,
        budget: 55000000
    },
    totalRevenue: function () {
        let x = this.movie.boxOffice - this.movie.budget;
        return x;
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `this` belong to movie object, so remove movie from your function you can directly invoke `boxoffice` and `budget` because it is belong to the `this`

```
let movie = {
  title: "Forrest Gump",
  director: "Robert Zemeckis",
  composer: "Alan Silvestri",
  budget: 55000000,
  boxOffice: 677900000,
  awards: [],

  totalRevenue: function () {
    let x = this.boxOffice - this.budget;
    return x;
  },
};

movie.totalRevenue(); // will return 622900000
```

And one more thing your code is not going in infinite loop rather than it is unable to find `movie` inside `this`